# Under what conditions, $(A-B)∪(A-C) = A$ is true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For any sets $A, B$ and $C$ that are subsets of a universal set $U$, under what conditions is $$(A-B)\cup(A-C) = A$$ true?

I have no idea how to solve this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you to show that $(A-B)\cup (A-C)= A-(B\cap C)$

Comment: Start by playing with examples. Try to get a feel of this statement.

Comment: If the three set are mutually disjoint $$A\cap B=\emptyset;\;A\cap C=\emptyset;\;C\cap B=\emptyset$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Assume that there exists a $x\in U$ such that $x \in A\cap B$ and $x\in A\cap C$. Then $x$ is certainly in $A$, (the set on the RHS of the equation), but $x$ is not in $(A-B)\cup(A-C)$, (the set on the LHS of the equation). Hence, the equation does not hold. Show that this is the only the case.